# How use Ioc structuremap for quartz?

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, structuremap, quartz.net, ijobfactory

I have tried use current example, but I get the error:
https://gist.github.com/mhenrixon/772643

```
ForSingletonOf<IScheduler>().Use(ctx =>
        {
            var scheduler = ctx.GetInstance<ISchedulerFactory>().GetScheduler();
            scheduler.JobFactory = ctx.GetInstance<IJobFactory>();
            return scheduler;
        });
```

The error: “A lambda expression with a statement body cannot be converted to an expression tree”.

Actually I need solution for use IoC for **IJobFactory**

Answer (score 1):

I use something like this:

```
        ForSingletonOf<IScheduler>().Use("A description",ctx =>
        {
            var scheduler = ctx.GetInstance<ISchedulerFactory>().GetScheduler();
            scheduler.JobFactory = ctx.GetInstance<IJobFactory>();
            return scheduler;
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that in this scenario you can only use simple expressions (without a "statement body" - meaning curly braces) to the right of the => ("goes to") operator - the lambda expression probably needs to be converted to an expression tree.

You could wrap all that inside a factory pattern (on top of those already existing factory interfaces...factorception):

```
public interface ICustomSchedulerFactory
{
    Scheduler Create();
}

public class CustomSchedulerFactory: ICustomSchedulerFactory
{
    private readonly IContainer _container;
    public CustomSchedulerFactory(IContainer container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    public Scheduler Create()
    {
        var scheduler = _container.GetInstance<ISchedulerFactory>().GetScheduler();
        scheduler.JobFactory = _container.GetInstance<IJobFactory>();
        return scheduler;
    }
}
```

(or simply inject the required dependencies instead of the container)
and then simply

```
ForSingletonOf<IScheduler>().Use(ctx => ctx.GetInstance<ICustomSchedulerFactory>().Create());
```